# Can a single CALayer be used as the mask for multiple other layers?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, mask

I can't find anything in the docs that indicates whether a single CALayer (or subclass) can be used as the `mask` property for multiple other layers. Is it possible? Or undefined?

Comment: Bizarrely you can NOT do this.  Each layer has to have it's own mask layer!  If you have to use the same mask, you indeed have to duplicate it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experimentation says that it cannot. It will end up as the mask for the last layer it is attached to, and any previous layers it was assigned as a mask to, will revert to the default value of mask.

Comment: Travis, if you see this .. your old QA seems to be exactly correct!  Bizarre right?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.
I combined mask of CAGradationLayer and CAShapeLayer.

I made `UIImage` from two layers, and I use it to mask.

You can generate image from CALayer like below.

```
extension CALayer {
    func makeImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
        self.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

and You can mask by multiple layers.

```
firstMask.mask = secondMask
let img = firstMask.makeImage()// require firstMask.frame

let combinedMask = CALayer()
combinedMask.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, img.size.width, img.size.height)
combinedMask.contents = img.CGImage

yourLayer.mask = combinedMask
```